# API: sqs:CreateQueue always ACCESS DENIED

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to create an sqs queue with cloudformation but I keep getting this error in the console.

```
API: sqs:CreateQueue Access to the resource https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ is denied.
```

Obviously I'm missing some sort of permission. This [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-sqs-queues.html) didn't really specify how I could resolve this.

Here's the code I made:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"

Resources:

  MyQueue:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
    Properties:
      FifoQueue: false
      QueueName: sqs-test
      ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds: 20
      RedrivePolicy:
        deadLetterTargetArn:
          Fn::GetAtt:
          - "MyDLQ"
          - "Arn"
        maxReceiveCount: 4
      Tags:
      -
        Key: "ProjectName"
        Value: "project-x"

  MyDLQ:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
    Properties:
      FifoQueue: false
      QueueName: sqs-dlq-test
```

I'm trying to understand this [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-writing-an-sqs-policy.html). But I'm not sure how I could attach a policy to allow creation of queues. Someone please give me a full example.

Comment: I'm assuming you are running this as your own IAM user. What is the IAM policy on that user? The user running the CloudFormation template needs to have permissions to create the same resources.

Answer (score 0):

tyron's comment on your question is spot on. Check permissions of the user executing the CloudFormation. If you're running commands directly, this is usually pretty easy to check. In some cases, you may be working with a more complicated environment with automation.

I find the best way to troubleshoot permissions in an automated world is via CloudTrail. After any API call has failed, whether from the CLI, CloudFormation, or another source, you can look up the call in CloudTrail.

In this case, searching for "Event Name" = "CreateQueue" in the time range of the failure will turn up a result with details like the following:

- **Source IP Address**; this field may say something like cloudformation.amazonaws.com, or the IP of your machine/office. Helpful when you need to filter events based on the source.
- **User name**; In my case, this was the EC2 instance ID of the agent running the CFN template.
- **Access Key ID**; For EC2 instances, this is likely a set of temporary access credentials, but for a real user, it will show you what key was used.
- **Actual event data**; Especially helpful for non-permissions errors, the actual event may show you errors in the request itself.

In my case, the specific EC2 instance that ran automation was out of date and needed to be updated to use the correct IAM Role/Instance Profile. CloudTrail helped me track that down.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AWS CodePipeline (where you may be using AWS CodeBuild to run & deploy your CloudFormation stack), remember your **CodeBuild role** (created under IAM Roles) must have the correct permissions.

You can identify which role is being used & attach required policies -

1. Open CodeBuild Project
2. Go to Build Details > Environment > Service Role
3. Open Service Role (hyperlinked)
4. Add SQS to role policies